# How to access child state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made my own form component with render() method looks like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} ref={(c)=>this._form=c}>
            {this.props.children}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Notice that children are rendered here as `{this.props.children}`, so the user can use this component like this:

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.submit}   >
            <Input  name={"name"} id="name"  labelName="Ime" placeholder="Unesite ime" type="text" >
                 <Validation rule="required" message="Ovo je obavezno polje"/>
            </Input>
            <Input  name={"email"} id="email"  labelName="Email" placeholder="Unesite email adresu" type="text" >
                <Validation rule="required" message="Ovo je obavezno polje"/>
                <Validation rule="email" message="Ovo je nije valjana email adresa"/>
            </Input>
            <button type="submit" value="Pošalji" >Pošalji</button>
       </Form>
```

I would like to check the state of each `Input` component (to get its validity) inside `onSubmitMethod()`.

```
  checkValidity() {
    var sefl = this;
    this.props.children.map((child) => {
        if (child.type.name === "Input") {

//How to get state of child here
        }
    });
}
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj = serialize(this._form, { hash: true });
    const validityOfForm = true; //hardcoded for now
    this.checkValidity();
    this.props.onSubmit(obj, validityOfForm);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done similar thing in a project by passing state of parent as a prop in child to access child component data in parent component for form elements.

In your case if you send  component's state in its child as a prop and each child use state of parent like this.props.state.variablename and not this.state.variablename. You will have control on child components' states / data.

Sending state to childrens from form component using this.prop.children as a prop is not straight forward. Below link helps in doing this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371612/1708333

**Example:**

**Parent component:**

```
<FormFields
    state={this.state}
    _onChange={this._onChange}
/>
```

**Child component**

```
<Input
    name="fieldname"
    value={this.props.state.fieldname}
    type="text"
    label="Lable text"
    validationMessage={this.props.state.validationMessages.fieldname} 
    onChange={this.props._onChange}
/>
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `ref`, say `myinput`, to the child and get its state by `this.refs.myinput.state` to access the child's state if you have to.

However, take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849319/react-is-accessing-the-state-of-children-an-anti-pattern) before you put the `ref`. There is a better pattern.

Comment: Yes, but input ref is not ref of a Form component, so when I say this.refs inside Form component I get undefined

Comment: Other problem I have now is thats this.refs.myinput.state only returns state that was defined first time (inside conctructor) not up to date state.

Answer (score 0):

Input should have ref defined. That is easy.
But because Inputs are defined inside Form's parent component (altought rendered inside Form component (because of `{this.props.children}`)
I should access `Form` component's parent using `child_owner._instance` . Relevant part of code is now:

```
   checkValidity() {
    var sefl = this;
    var errorsCount = 0;
    this.props.children.map((child) => {

        if (child.type.name === "Input") {
            var refs = child._owner._instance.refs;
            var rules = refs[child.ref].state.validationRules;
            var hiddenRules = refs[child.ref].state.validationRulesHidden;
            if (_.filter(_.values(rules), (elem) => elem == true).length > 0 || _.filter(_.values(hiddenRules), (elem) => elem == true).length>0) {
                errorsCount++;
            }
      }

    });
    if (errorsCount == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is an [API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map) to map React children, FYI.